# Variables stay at 0 and is unable to change based on user input

Tags: java, variables

I'm a newbie to Java and tried making a very simple money calculator. The rest of the code works fine, except I'm unable to change the instance values - they stay constantly at 0 instead of using the user input, and I was wondering what I was doing wrong.

```
package src;
```

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sterling {

```
private static int Money;
private static int Deposit;
private static int percentage;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Moneys = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Money.");
    int Money = Moneys.nextInt();
    getMoney();
    System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
    String a = Moneys.next();
    if (a.equals("Percentage")) {
        System.out.println("Enter Percentage.");
        int Percentage = Moneys.nextInt();
        percentage();
    } else if (a.equals("Deposit")) {
        System.out.println("Enter Deposit amount.");
        int Deposit = Moneys.nextInt();
        Deposit();
    }
}

private static void Deposit() {
        Money = Deposit + Money;
        System.out.println(Money);

    }

private static void percentage() {
    Money = percentage * Money;
    System.out.println(Money);

}

private static void getMoney() {
    System.out.println(Money);
}
```

}

Comment: You've overshadowed your `static int Money` field with a local variable `int Money`, i.e. there are two different `Money` variables. If you're new to Java, I would avoid the usage of `static` until you are more familiar with it. `static` is essentially a memory tool, not an access tool.

Comment: When you say `int Money = Moneys.nextInt();` inside `main` you're creating a new local variablle, not using the class data.

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Variable names should start with lower case character. And don’t call your package *src*

Comment: Thank you! I'll make sure to edit my code and work on my naming conventions, and variable types.

Answer (score 0):

This will resolve the issues, but still you should take care of your naming conventions as @Jens said. and should not use static variables until you know what they are supposed to do.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner Moneys = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Money.");
    Money = Moneys.nextInt();
    getMoney();
    System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
    String a = Moneys.next();
    if (a.equals("Percentage"))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Percentage.");
        percentage = Moneys.nextInt();
        percentage();
    }
    else if (a.equals("Deposit"))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Deposit amount.");
        Deposit = Moneys.nextInt();
        Deposit();
    }
}
```

}